# how to make sails-linker load different assets in sub/child pages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, pug, asset-pipeline

Please see attachment.

[image]

That's the template structure. login.jade extends layout.jade.

My problem is that I want:

1. a global.css file loaded in all pages (done)
2. login.css file loaded only when viewing login.jade (problem)

I already created a working pipeline configuration. The task looks like this:

```
devStyles: {
    options: {
        startTag: '<!--STYLES-->',
        endTag: '<!--STYLES END-->',
        fileTmpl: '<link rel="stylesheet" href="%s">',
        appRoot: '.tmp/public'
    },
    files: {
        '.tmp/public/**/*.html': require('../pipeline').frontendGlobalCssFiles,
        'views/**/*.html': require('../pipeline').frontendGlobalCssFiles,
        'views/**/*.jade': require('../pipeline').frontendGlobalCssFiles,
        'views/auth/login.jade': require('../pipeline').frontendLoginCssFiles
    }
}
```

The problem is that the last files rule doesn't work. I'm sure that frontendLoginCssFiles is ok, since if I load it with the `'views/**/*.jade'` path, it works. So what's the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, solved. Basically, the problem is not strictly related to jade inheritance. What sails-linker really does is add the assets to the physical files, no matter if they're parents, children or partials. All it does is take the passed files, search for the proper start/end Tags and add the related html BEFORE compiling the real served pages.

My problem was that I was not adding the start/end tags to the login (child) page.

Anyway, even doing so, we've got then the problem that ALL the compiled pages will load ALL the assets. So for example, the login assets will be also loaded on the home page. Not so good.

To solve, briefly, I **used specific start/end tags for page-specific assets**.
Following, the 'long' story:

Note: since we're speaking about jade templates, in sails-linker we are looking into the *Jade tasks, and therefore the comments are written with jade syntax (ex. `// STYLES` and not `<!--STYLES-->`)

First, we'll isolate 'global assets' > the ones we want to load on every page:

1. Change all the `// STYLES` instances to something like `// GLOBAL STYLES`. Both in sails-linker and eventually on .jade views.
2. /tasks/pipeline.js: rename default filelists to something like `globalCssFiles`, jsfiles etc, and change all the instances of that name.
3. /tasks/config/sails-linker.js: rename all the instances of point 2 modifications.

Second, we'll add 'page assets':

1. On child jade pages, use something like `// PAGE STYLES` comments.
2. /tasks/pipeline.js: create page-specific filelists, so ex:

   `var frontendLoginCss = ['styles/login.css'];`

and below:

```
module.exports.frontendLoginCss = frontendLoginCss.map(function(path) {
  return '.tmp/public/' + path;
});
```

3. /tasks/config/sails-linker.js: create page-specific tasks, like:

   ```
   devPageStylesJade: {
      options: {
          startTag: '// PAGE STYLES',
          endTag: '// PAGE STYLES END',
          fileTmpl: 'link(rel="stylesheet", href="%s")',
          appRoot: '.tmp/public'
      },
      files: {
          'views/auth/login.jade': require('../pipeline').frontendLoginCss
      }
   }
   ```
4. /tasks/register/*: add the relevant tasks in all the files where you should to. For example, my linkAssets.js could be like this:

   ```
   module.exports = function (grunt) {
      grunt.registerTask('linkAssets', [
          'sails-linker:devJs',
          'sails-linker:devStyles',
          'sails-linker:devTpl',
          'sails-linker:devJsJade',
          'sails-linker:devPageJsJade', //added
          'sails-linker:devStylesJade',
          'sails-linker:devPageStylesJade', //added
          'sails-linker:devTplJade'
      ]);
   };
   ```
5. In jade templates, use block syntax for importing the styles/js, so you can use append to append the assets to the block. Ex, the general 'parent' layout.jade will have:

   ```
    block styles
       // GLOBAL STYLES
       // GLOBAL STYLES END
   ```

while the child template login.jade will have:

```
     append styles
        // PAGE STYLES
        // PAGE STYLES END
```

Final tip: it really doesn't matter where you write the append directives in child templates, they'll always appended where the parent template did defined them. So I'll write all appends on the bottom of my child templates (more clean).

Hope will be usefull for people with same issues!